# How can I create an alphabetical order with a file as database? C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem, I have a file that saves student data and their characteristics such as name, grade, average etc. I searched the entire internet, I think. The problem is mainly that I do not know how to combine, for example, alphabetical sorting after pressing a specific key. Is it about rereading the file from the student database or can you work around it somehow?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define KEY_L 76 //- alfabetyczny porzadek
#define KEY_K 75 //- zapis studentow i pliku
#define KEY_U 85 //- usuniecie studenta z 2.5 srocen
#define KEY_D 68 //- dodanie nowego studenta(im,nazw,wiek,sro,nralb)
#define KEY_X 88 //- wyjscie

struct Osoba{

    string imie;
    string nazwisko;
    int nrAlbumu;
    float srOcen;
    int wiek;
};


int main(){

fstream plik;

plik.open( "studenci.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

Osoba uczniowie[20];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "podaj imie i nazwisko " << i+1 << " ucznia: " ;
    cin >> uczniowie[i].imie;
    cin >> uczniowie[i].nazwisko;
}

cout << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "podaj numer albumu " << uczniowie[i].imie <<" "<< uczniowie[i].nazwisko <<" ";
    cin >> uczniowie[i].nrAlbumu;
}

cout << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "podaj wiek " << uczniowie[i].imie <<" "<< uczniowie[i].nazwisko <<" ";
    cin >> uczniowie[i].wiek;
}

cout << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "podaj srednia ocen: " << uczniowie[i].imie <<" "<< uczniowie[i].nazwisko <<" ";
    cin >> uczniowie[i].srOcen;
}

cout << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
plik << uczniowie[i].imie <<" "<< uczniowie[i].nazwisko <<" "<< uczniowie[i].wiek <<" "<< uczniowie[i].nrAlbumu <<" "<< uczniowie[i].srOcen << endl;
} 


plik.close();

plik.open( "studenci.txt", ios::in );


if(plik.is_open())
    {
        char wiersz[10000];

        while(plik.getline(wiersz,10000)) 
        {
            cout<< wiersz << endl;
            
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

cout << "          MENU LISTY UCZNIOW:       " << endl;
cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "..(K).. - Zapis aktualnego stanu.." << endl;
cout << "..(L).. - Listowanie Listy alfabetycznie.." << endl;
cout << "..(U).. - Usuniecie studenta ze sr.ocen 2.5.." << endl;
cout << "..(D).. - Dodanie nowego studenta i jego cech(imie,nazwisko,wiek,srOcen,nrAlbumu) nie wiecej niz 20 uczniow.." << endl;
cout << "..(X).. - Wyjscie z programu.." << endl;
cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;



char key = getch();
int value = key;

while(value != KEY_X){
    switch(getch()){

        case KEY_L : //listowanie

        plik.open( "studenci.txt", ios::in );


        if(plik.is_open())
    {
        char wiersz[10000];

        while(plik.getline(wiersz,10000)) 
        {
            cout << wiersz << endl;
            
        }
        cout << endl;

    }

    //zapis
    for(int i; i < sizeof(uczniowie)/sizeof(uczniowie[i]); i++){
    plik.open( "studenci.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
   
    //  sort(uczniowie, uczniowie + 5);
    //  for(auto ele: uczniowie){
    //      cout << ele << ", " << endl;
    //  }

    plik.close();
    }

        

        plik.open( "studenci.txt", ios::in );


        if(plik.is_open())
    {
        char wiersz[10000];

        while(plik.getline(wiersz,10000)) 
        {
            cout << wiersz << endl;
            
        }
        cout << endl;

    }
        
        cout << "Nazwiska zostały wylistowane!" << endl;

        break;

        case KEY_D : //dodawanie

        cout<<endl;

        break;

        case KEY_U : //usuniecie

        cout<<endl;

        break;

        case KEY_K : //zapis

        cout<<endl;

        break;
        
        default: //wyjscie
        exit(1);
    }
}

key = getch();
value = key;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about saving your content in a `std::vector` and then `std::sort` that?

Comment: generally it doesn't read to me "sort" in the middle after pressing a specific key. What I tried is marked (commented out) :/

Comment: "Is it about rereading the file from the student database or can you work around it somehow?" confusing... Can you improve the question?

Comment: viz in what confusing session? I don't understand, it's about getting around a one-time entry and exit with a while operation

Comment: So, what you want to do is sorting the datafile by pressing a key?

Comment: I mean sorting the names, nothing else :)

Comment: I keep getting an error and I have no idea how I can do it with the structure above